# How can I correctly combine an input tag with an ActionLink button?

Tags: html, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

I have two btn btn-default buttons displaying in-line, but the hover effect of the second one (the ActionLink button) is not taking on the same properties of the first.  The first one looks like it has some Css targeting the input tag, so I was figuring to give that input tag to the second button; however, I can't seem to integrate it correctly without errors.  Could anyone point me in the direction of combining an input tag with an ActionLink button?

Here's my code for both buttons, the "Create" button is on top, and it's the one with the input tag that I want to also give to the "Back to List" button on the bottom.  I haven't included Css for now, as my issue is more to do with html. But if it is necessary, please let me know.

```
 <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
            </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">              
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "btn btn-default", @role = "button" })

            </div>
        </div>
```

I appreciate any and all answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no `btn-default` anymore in `bootstrap4`. Use `btn-secondary` instead. That should give you the hover effect you want consistently.
2. Just so you know you don't have to use `<input />` for your submit button. You can just use the regular `<button />` with the right type:

   ```
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Create</button>
   ```

   So you don't have to stick with the thinking that you have to use an input tag for the other button.
3. `@Html.ActionLink()` will generate an anchor tag `<a href="# />` unless you override it, so you can't use it to generate an input tag anyway.

Comment: Thank you David!  I will forget about the input tag in that case, and change it to button type. I appreciate this solution!

Answer (score 1):

This Works for me. Not super clean looking.

```
    <div class="input-group">
         <div class="input-group-addon">
               @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new {@class = "btn btn-default", @role = "button" })
         </div>
         <input class="text-box single-line form-control" style="width:100%;">
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Ricky! I liked the solution, but for some reason it was making an orange border appear, so I ended up going a different route. This was a helpful solution though!